# How to make a TextBox/Status Box in pygame for an rpg?

Tags: python, text, pygame

I need to create a TextBox / MessageBox /StatusBox etc. for my rpg. I have made a Text Box 
class but it does not seem to work. It blits the surface but doesnt display any text.

CODE:

```
class TextBox(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.initFont()
        self.initImage()
        self.initGroup()
        self.setText(['a','b'])

    def initFont(self):
        pygame.font.init()
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None,3)

    def initImage(self):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((200,80))
        self.image.fill((255,255,255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (0,0)        

    def setText(self,text):
        tmp = pygame.display.get_surface()
        x_pos = self.rect.left+5
        y_pos = self.rect.top+5

        for t in text:
            x = self.font.render(t,False,(0,0,0))
            tmp.blit(x,(x_pos,y_pos))
            x_pos += 10

            if (x_pos > self.image.get_width()-5):
                x_pos = self.rect.left+5
                y_pos += 10

    def initGroup(self):
        self.group = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
        self.group.add(self)
```

Comment: If you find the answer to your own question, you should post it as an answer, so you can mark off the question as answered. I think you will have to wait 24 hours from the time you asked the question to do this.

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant to do it but had to wait for 24 hours, so i made an edit instead. Its done now.

Comment: Cool. Also you can tick off your own question. ;)

Comment: LOL! I did that! Got extra reputation without any pains! :D

Comment: :D Well don't think of it as "cheating". It is designed this way. Even though you weren't helping someone else, you still added a new entry with a valid solution into a Q&A database, so you deserve a bit of reputation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Umm Sorry. Never Mind. I found the problem myself. I wrote :

```
 self.rect.center = (0,0)
```

where it should have been

```
 self.rect.top = 0 ; self.rect.left = 0
```

Thanks Anyway. :D

Comment: Use: `self.rect.topleft = (0, 0)`